# What does しゅごい mean?

Tags: pronunciation, slang, phrase-requests, reading-comprehension

I'm reading a manga and I can't for the life of me figure out what this phrase is supposed to mean; I've never seen it before.

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure, but I *think* this was downvoted because a Google search for しゅごい immediately answers the question.

Comment: If that was the reason for downvoting, I'd like to point out that [a Google search for "しゅごい"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%97%E3%82%85%E3%81%94%E3%81%84%22) only answers the question if you can read Japanese reasonably well.  Someone whose vocabulary and experience is limited enough to where they're thrown by this "lisp" (a relatable problem for beginning studiers) would probably not be able to read through the hits enough to understand the solution.  I.e., I don't think the downvote is warranted.  YMMV, yada yada.

Comment: I would say that the format of the question wasn’t very good. しゅごい is easily typeable, but the original question (see question history) didn’t put the query term in plain text and gave an impression that the OP can’t read hiragana.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a slurred or lisped version of すごい ("awesome").

Slurred or lisped pronunciation is often marked in Japanese by using different kana.  In the example above, す is swapped out for しゅ.  Years ago, my wife had a DoCoMo phone that had an animated bear that would appear and say various things in a funny lisped accent, where all the "s" sounds were swapped out for "f" sounds.  The bear would say things like げんき でふぉう, or とても ふき でふ！

---

Please comment if the above does not address your question.

Comment: +1 slurred or lisped, or drunk, or baby talk, and so on.